# Delete object from embers list on button click

Tags: ember.js

I have todo list http://jsfiddle.net/WKn3P/15/

```
Todos.todosController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    createTodo: function(title){
        var todo = Todos.Todo.create({ title: title });
        this.pushObject(todo);    
    },

    removeTodo: function(view){
        this.removeObject(view.context);
        debug;
    },

});
```

I am trying to make "delete button", which give opportunity to remove object in the list.
But now it doesn't work. Additionally, I don't understand why "data-ember-action="1" appears here.
I read all Ember.js guide, and google a lot, but totally lost. Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

> > I don't understand why "data-ember-action="1" appears here

The {{action}} should be inside the tag:

```
<button {{action removeTodo}}>Remove</button>
```

Yours was outside (with the text).

That said, there were several issues with the fiddle.  I fixed them, you can check the [[new updated version here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKn3P/16/)

Main issues were:

- Routes are a very important part of Ember.js.  You need to take them into consideration when building the app.  They are the glue between controllers and models, and they're the ones that render the templates.
- You should not create the controllers manually, let Ember.js create them for you.
  Instead of `Todos.todosController = Em.ArrayController.create()`, use `Todos.TodosController = Em.ArrayController.extend()`.

There were other minor things which I fixed.  Take a look at the updated fiddle and spot these changes.

Good luck! :)